# passing a pointer as argument to a function in C

Tags: c, pointers

Something I stumbled upon and made me wonder.
Why does this work?

```
void foo (int* a)
{
    int x = 3;
    *a = x;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    foo(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

But this causes a segmentation fault (both on Visual Studio 2008 and gcc)?

```
void foo (int* a)
{
    int x = 3;
    *a = x;
}

int main()
{
    int* a;
    foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it something defined in the language or just an implementation issue?

Comment: You should be getting a warning with the second example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare

```
int* a;
```

You are declaring a pointer variable `a` but you are not making it point to anything. Then in the function, you do

```
*a = x;
```

Which dereferences the pointer and tries to assign what it points to the value of `x`. But since it doesn't point to anything, you get undefined behaviour, manifested in a segmentation fault.

You should do this:

```
int i; // the actual integer variable
int* a = &i; // a points to i
```

The difference between that and the first one is that `int a;` declares a real integer variable, then you take its address with `&a` and passes it to the function. The pointer `a` inside the function `foo` points to the variable `a` in `main`, and so dereferencing it and assigning to it is perfectly fine.

Comment: Also problematic: `printf("%d\n", a);`, since `"%d"` expects type `int` but `a` is type `int *`.

Comment: Thanks. The segmentation fault happens even without the printf so I deleted it from the question

Comment: @DigitalDa did you not read the top 3/4 of my post? The segmentation fault is not because of the `printf`, it's because you're creating a pointer that doesn't point to anything and then assigning `x` to what it points to (which is nothing)

Comment: @Seth Carnegie I did. The printf is irrelevant

Comment: @DigitalDa no, it's a problem in the program. Just because it doesn't make it crash doesn't mean it's not a problem; you can't use the `%d` specifier with pointers because pointers and integers may be different sizes. It was the second thing that is incorrect in the second program.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie I know it is a problem, but I wanted to keep the question relevant to the title and the print format was not the issue.

Comment: @DigitalDa ok then, I'll remove that paragraph from my answer.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie and order was restored to the world :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int a;
```

Assigns memory as soon as you declare it but this not the case with int *a;

```
int *a;
```

is pointer declaration (MEMORY not yet allocated for that).

```
int *a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); // allocate memory
```